# Random URL on deploying azure static web app

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I have a deployed a static web application using a YAML task:

```
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    name: DeployStaticWebApp
    displayName: Deploy Static Web App
    inputs:
      app_location: 'web-app'
      cwd: 'package'
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(token)
```

I see a random URL after every deployment as you see here. How do I set a hardcoded URL via deployment?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Random URL on deploying azure static web app

Yes, by default `Azure Static Web App` auto-generates domain URL.

The option available to access the Static WebApp with another URL is to Configure a new `Custom domain`.

You can see [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain?tabs=azure-dns) mentions the same.

> By default, Azure Static Web Apps provides an auto-generated domain name for your website, but you can point a custom domain to your site.

Even if we configure the custom domain, the auto-generated `URL` cannot be changed, just a new domain is added in the `Custom domain` section.

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain-azure-dns) to Configure custom domain for `Azure Static WebApp`.***

I have observed that the auto-generated URL name is same as the workflow file last name.

```cs
Ex: 
URL - https://orange-smoke-099cdb110.2.azurestaticapps.net
Workflow name - azure-static-web-apps-orange-smoke-099cdb110.yml
```

I have tried to change the `yml` file name and run the job again. Unable to change it.